# Is there a way to override javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist() method in openjpa

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I want to intercept the JPA calls (without touching entity classes) and hence need $subject? Has anybody tried something similar.

Comment: Hi Chris and dcernahoschi
Thanks for the clue and both are quite useful information for me. I think this is exactly I would need. I did EXACTLY as dcernahoschi mentioned. But the listener did not get hit. I can debug the openjpa EntityManager and etc. How can I know whether my listener got registered. Or anything missing in the given configuration ?

Comment: please, take a look at my updated answer at xml configuration. There are 2 more tags added.

Comment: Same result. I put logs in each method in listener. I think my listener might not get registered. In this case it is Apache JUDDI's persistence layer that I am dealing with. So I added a newly created orm.xml file inside the jar. META-INF/  where persistence.xml is also resides. Seems it is not picking in that place. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, the location of the orm.xml is fine. Try to specify explicitly the location in persistence.xml file with: `<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>`

Comment: And be careful at the order of elements in `persistence.xml` when adding `<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>`. The order should be consistent with `persistence.xsd` otherwise you'll get validation errors at startup.

Answer (score 1):

Every container out there creates a proxy EM, so you can easily look at how spring or glassfish do it.  In the persistence.xml you specify the provider class to use, so just point it to your implementation.

But you could just add in event listeners using an ORM.xml file - JPA allows adding default listeners that apply to all entities, so you do not need to touch any of them.  What exactly are you after that JPA doesn't already provide?

Comment: HI Chris,
In fact I tried it, but when I specify the class it does not get picked up. What I did was like, MyProvider extends openjpa.PersistenceProviderImpl. Have to checkout how glassfish/spring does it. \

Comment: You need your provider class to be registered with the Persistence class for it to be picked up.  It will need a META-INF\services\javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider file that specifies your provider class so that it knows it is a JPA provider to be used with your persistence unit.  Going through listeners is the better approach though.

Comment: I have already added the provider class name to persistence.xml and javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider file. Yes, going through the listeners is the better way,but for some reason it is not getting hit.Is there a way to check whether my listeners are registered in openjpa?

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept JPA life-cycle events like "onPersist" by specifying default entity listeners for all entities in the `orm.xml` file. There is no need to touch the entity. For example:

```
class SomeListener { 
   @PrePersist
   private void prePersist(Object entity){
      //do some stuff before persisting the entity
   }

   @PostPersist
   private void postPersist(Object entity){
       //do some staff after persisting the entity
   }
}

<entity-mappings>
  <persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
       <entity-listeners>
          <entity-listener class="SomeListener">
          <pre-persist method-name="prePersist"/>
          <post-persist method-name="postPersist"/>
        </entity-listener>
       </entity-listeners>
     </persistence-unit-defaults>
  </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings
```